# How can I give my id the Mongoose ObjectID? Of the whole object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I would like to give my id from basicData the ObjectID of my whole Company object. How is this possible?
I've tried so: `_id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Company" }` but it doesn't work...
Do you have a solution?

my code:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document, Collection, mongo } from "mongoose";

const CompanySchema = new Schema(
  {
    basicData: {
      _id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, auto: true }, // that id I want to give her the complete ObjectID of Company
      tasks: {
        type: [],
        validate: {
          validator: (arr: any) => {
            return arr.length > 0;
          },
          message: "You must provide more than 0 tasks.",
        },
        title: { type: String, required: [true, "title is required"] },
      },
      partner: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "partner is required"],
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
      },
      riskFactor: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "riskFactor is required"],
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
      },
      name: { type: String, required: [true, "name is required"] },
    },
  },
  {
    versionKey: false,
    typePojoToMixed: false,
  }
);
const Company = mongoose.model("Company", CompanySchema);
export default Company;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a basicSchema in your companySchema file and it'll be automatically get an `_id` when inserted:

```js
// Company.js

const BasicDataSchema = new Schema({
      tasks: {
        type: [],
        validate: {
          validator: (arr: any) => {
            return arr.length > 0;
          },
          message: "You must provide more than 0 tasks.",
        },
        title: { type: String, required: [true, "title is required"] },
      },
      partner: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "partner is required"],
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
      },
      riskFactor: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "riskFactor is required"],
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
      },
      name: { type: String, required: [true, "name is required"] }
});

const CompanySchema = new Schema({
 basicData: BasicDataSchema,
 ...
});
```

Comment: Well, not quite my goal is to have a field called id in the basicData and this id should have the id of the whole object so I can find my object using this id.